# How to keep specific values in a column and a remove the other values to new columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that has 6 columns. One of these columns named "customer information" holds values such as "UNKNOWN", place name, street name, or city name. However, this column should only include either "UNKNOWN" or place name. How can I have the street name and city name to move two new columns? I have performed searches online using various ket terms, however I was not able to find something that would be helpful.

[image: Column holding various values]

[Dataframe content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LF9w0.jpg)

Comment: How do you distinguish place name from street/city name?

Comment: An example for place name is: Lionhart MMA and Fitness. It can also be person name such as Jack Callison. Street name include building number and street name. Lastly, city name includes Moncks corner, SC, 29461.

Comment: So do streets and city names always have numbers in them? And is anything with a number in it always a street or city name? 
If so, create a new column containing only values without numbers in them.

Comment: I believe they do. There are three other columns (service number, account number, x_6) that also include numbers.

Comment: Let me know if the version below works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using tidyverse. Assuming your dataset is named df.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(unk_place_only = if_else(grepl("\\d", customer_information), 
                                  as.character(NA),
                                  customer_information),
         city_name = if_else(grepl("Moncks Corner", customer_information), 
                             customer_information,
                             as.character(NA)),
         # Assumes street names always start with a number
         street_name = if_else(grepl("^[[:digit:]]+", customer_information),
                               customer_information,
                               as.character(NA)))
```

The new variable contains place name and unknown only. I'd need more information on the differences between street and city name to be able to separate those out.

Comment: Thank you. I added a new image, which shows the fields data frame contains. I had to redact the data for service number and account number. The format of service number is '999999' and a format of account number is '999999'. Hope this helps.

Comment: Does the solution above work?
Is there anything else which needs to happen for your question to be answered?

Comment: Few questions: What does "unknown's_place_only" represent? As for if_else, do you mean ifelse? Lastly, should I replace bywords with something else?

Comment: `unk_place_only` is the name of the new variable containing only place names and the word `UNKNOWN`.
`if_else()` should work, as long as you load tidyverse. It's better than `ifelse` here, because it's vectorised.
I've edited my answer to remove the `mywords` bit, apologies.

Comment: As for city names (ex. moncks corner, sc 29461) and street names (ex. 538 alderly drive), will they be moving to two new columns?

Comment: The code you provided above worked perfectly. As I mentioned in my previous comment, is it possible to move the city names and street names to two new columns as well?

Comment: What's the difference between city and street names?
Do city names always have a postcode in a format similar to SC 99999?

Comment: Street names provide building numbers as well as street names (ex. 538 Alderly drive, 102 California drive, etc.). As for city names they provide city names, state and postcode (ex. Moncks Corner, SC 29461). For the project I am doing we are concentrating on only one city, Moncks Corner. The city names always have a postcode.

Comment: I've edited to separate city and street names. Does it work?

Comment: I tried the code you provided above but it gives me this error Error in FUN(left) : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: Try now. It was a typo.